# How fetch 10 records each time from table using coredata

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data

I want to fetch 10 records from database. once the first 10 records are fetched, next time I want to fetch another 10 record from the database using coredata.

Also want to handle the condition like - After fetching some records at the end if there is less than 10 record in the table how to handle this.

Comment: Fire query `SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLENAME LIMIT 10;`

Comment: for next 10 records `SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLENAME  WHERE `'keyConditionIfAny'`='xyz' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`

Comment: Handle offset dynamically with your pagination code or if you don't want go with queries then 1st time `request.fetchOffset = 0; request.fetchLimit = 10;` & 2nd time  `request.fetchOffset = 10; request.fetchLimit = 10;`

Comment: @Mukesh thanks for the reply... Yes, I want to use NSFetchRequest. So how to handle the condition for less than 10 records.

Comment: Wait for sometime i will update in answer.

Comment: i have updated one generic answer accept it if its work for you.

Comment: Every time we are sending fetchLimit = 10, So my question is how to handle the condition when table have <10 records. For example we have 28 records in the table first and second time we got 10,10 records and third time we have only 8 records to fetch so how to fetch it.

Comment: No matters if tableView have less than 10 records, your array count is 10 so it will return under 10 records only. or you are asking about how to handle fetchOffSet?

Comment: OK got it !!  Thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that much answer is enough for your understanding,I am just uploading my working case & make sure fetchOffSet should 0 for 1st request & then **dynamic** as per your requirement,

Initially declare & initialize `NSInteger fetchOffSet = 0;`

**Objective-C**

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getCountryFromDB:(NSInteger)fetchOffSet {

NSMutableArray *_record = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

   NSManagedObjectContext *_context =[self getManagedObjectContext];
   NSFetchRequest *_fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    _fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10;
   _fetchRequest.fetchOffset = fetchOffSet;

   NSEntityDescription *_entityDesc =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
    [_fetchRequest setEntity:_entityDesc];

    NSError *_error;
    NSArray *_fetchedOjects = [_context executeFetchRequest:_fetchRequest error:&_error];

   for(int i=0;i<[_fetchedOjects count];i++) {
       Country *_country = [_fetchedOjects objectAtIndex:i];
       [_record addObject:_country];
    }
   return _record;
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

// UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis
CGFloat currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
CGFloat maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

// Change 50.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 50.0) {
     if(_yourCoreDataRecordArray.count > 10){
             fetchOffSet = fetchOffSet + 10;
            NSMutableArray *array = [self getCountryFromDB:fetchOffSet];

         }        
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
func getCountryFromDB(_ fetchOffSet: Int) -> [Any] {
    var record = [Any]() /* capacity: 0 */
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext? = self.getManagedObjectContext()
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    self.fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10
    self.fetchRequest.fetchOffset = fetchOffSet
    var entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Country", in: self.context)
    self.fetchRequest.entity = self.entityDesc
    var error: Error?
    var fetchedOjects: [Any]? = try? self.context.fetch(self.fetchRequest)
    for i in 0..<self.fetchedOjects.count {
        var country: Country? = self.fetchedOjects[i]
        self.record.append(self.country)
    }
    return self.record
}

 func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        // UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis
    var currentOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    var maximumOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
    // Change 50.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
    if maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 50.0 {
        if self.yourCoreDataRecordArray.count > 10 {
            fetchOffSet = fetchOffSet + 10
            var array: [Any] = self.getCountryFromDB(fetchOffSet)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For handling pagination i am considering you are fetching data properly,

While giving fetch request do this & handle offset dyanamically from your code,

```
// for 1st time first request
request.fetchOffset = 0;
request.fetchLimit = 10;

// for 2nd time second request
request.fetchOffset = 10;
request.fetchLimit = 10;
```

Answer (score 4):

just add these two properties into fetchrequest object

```
nsfetchrequest.fetchLimit = 10
nsfetchrequest.fetchOffset = 10 // this will be changed for every new call
```

Let me tell you in detail, the fetchLimit property used to tell the core data the maximum number of objects(record) that a request should return
and the fetchOffset skips a given set of results. If you set your offset to 2, then your first two results would not be returned in your results.

For more detail see the documentation:

http://www.learncoredata.com/how-to-fetch-data/

Cheers