# SwiftUI - How do I limit the number of objects displayed in a ForEach

Tags: swift, core-data, foreach, swiftui

I have a ForEach list in my app that pulls data from core data. Can I limit the number of objects that the ForEach list shows? for example, I want to only show the first 10 objects from my core data entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can limit the fetch from core data. see [How fetch 10 records each time from table using coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112829/how-fetch-10-records-each-time-from-table-using-coredata/42113406)

if youre looking to limit from ForEach instead of Core Data, you can iterator your collection using range:

```
ForEach(0 ..< 10) { index in 
  Text(Users[index].name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe in some cases the better solution would be to limit the fetchrequest, which is also quicker and less resource consuming

```
fetchrequest.fetchLimit = 10
```